# Floating bar chart with trend line on secondary axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am just tarting out trying to create visualizations with R/GGPLOT2.  The chart I am trying to acheive is a floating bar chart(one that has the bar go from one minimum to a maximum).  However, overlayed on top of this I would like a trend line that is on a secondary axis.  This has been my attempt so far:

```
# first, your data
table1 <- read.table(text = 'X  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L
                  1      "BAR TOP" 31.5 31.8 30.3 28.0 24.9 24.4 21.7 20.9 24.5 25.4 26.0 28.7
                  2      "TREND VALUE" 1000 1345 1234 1456 1324 1765 1567 1345 1556 1334 1224 1556
                  3      "BAR BOTTOM"  4.0  5.6  4.1 -1.3  0.0 -3.1 -2.6 -1.4 -0.8  2.0  2.7  4.1', header =T)


library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
# reshape to wide format (basically transposing the data.frame)
w <- dcast(melt(table1), variable~X)
p<-ggplot(w, aes(x=variable,ymin = `BAR BOTTOM`, 
          ymax = `BAR TOP`, lower = `BAR BOTTOM`, 
          upper = `BAR TOP`, middle = `BAR BOTTOM`)) + 
geom_boxplot(stat = 'identity') 

p <- p + labs(y = "BAR RANGE",
          x = "VARIABLE",
          colour = "Parameter")
p <- p + theme(legend.position = c(0.8, 0.9))
p
```

This is getting my the bars how I want them, however I am having trouble using the value TREND VALUE as a trend line on a secondary axis.  Any advice or direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest manually transform `TREND VALUE` into desired range and specify `sec.axis` with same transformation. I also will use `geom_rect()` instead of `geom_boxplot()`:

```
p <- ggplot(w) +
  aes(ymin = `BAR BOTTOM`,
      ymax = `BAR TOP`,
      xmin = as.numeric(variable) - .3,
      xmax = as.numeric(variable) + .3,
      x = as.numeric(variable),
      # Here we (roughly) transform `TREND VALUE` into range of BAR values
      y = `TREND VALUE`/100 
  ) +
  geom_rect(fill = 'white', col = 'black')+
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_continuous(labels = levels(w$variable),
                     breaks = 1:nlevels(w$variable))+
  # Specification for secondary axis - inverse transform of `TREND VALUE`
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = ~.*100)
```

Resulting plot:

```
p
```

[image]

### EDIT

Answering comment: we can specify almost any transformation:

Transform `x` values into range, `mn` - new minimum value, `mx` - new maximum:

```
trans_foo <- function(x, mn, mx) {
  (mx - mn)*((x - min(x))/(max(x) - min(x))) + mn
}
```

Back transformation:

```
itrans_foo <- function(y, min_x, max_x, mn, mx) {
  min_x + ((y - mn)*(max_x - min_x))/(mx - mn)
}
```

Now using this functions with `mx = 0` and `mn = 30` (minimum and maximum of the reversed BAR axis) & `scale_y_reverse()`, we will get the reversed primary axis and the normal secondary axis:

```
p <- ggplot(w) +
  aes(
    ymin = `BAR BOTTOM`,
    ymax = `BAR TOP`,
    xmin = as.numeric(variable) - .3,
    xmax = as.numeric(variable) + .3,
    x = as.numeric(variable),
    y = trans_foo(
      `TREND VALUE`,
      30, 0)
  ) +
  geom_rect(fill = "white", col = "black") +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(
    labels = levels(w$variable),
    breaks = 1:nlevels(w$variable)) +
  labs(
    y = "BAR RANGE",
    x = "VARIABLE",
    colour = "Parameter") +
  # Using scale_y_reverse will reverse the primary axis and
  # reverse the reversed secondary axis making it normal
  scale_y_reverse(sec.axis = sec_axis(
    trans = ~itrans_foo(
      .,
      min(w$`TREND VALUE`),
      max(w$`TREND VALUE`),
      30, 0
    ),
    name = "TREND"))

p
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you for the information.

Comment: The one issue I am running into now, is there a way to reverse the left had y axis, but not reverse the right hand y axis?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add a loess smoothed line with geom_smooth. In order to get it on the same axis, just rescale it.

```
    p<-ggplot(w, aes(x=variable,ymin = `BAR BOTTOM`, 
             ymax = `BAR TOP`, lower = `BAR BOTTOM`, 
             upper = `BAR TOP`, middle = `BAR BOTTOM`)) + 
             geom_boxplot(stat = 'identity') 
             + geom_smooth(aes(x = as.numeric(w$variable), y = w$`TREND VALUE`/100))
```

This will not result in a different axis, but dividing by 100 makes it easy to interpret still.

[See example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbCLN.png)