# Representing min, max, mean, and median for some data in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a table that has some data for news output per day and min, max, mean, and median are calculated each year. The data file is this:

[image]

I am trying to represent this data in a bar chart where the x-axis represents the year, and the y-axis represent the number of news stories. The desired bar chart needs to show the min, max, median, and mean for each year.

I am using read.table like this:

```
w <- read.table("C:/Users/shall/Desktop/minmaxmeanmedian.csv", sep= ",", header=TRUE, colClasses = "numeric")
```

Is this the right way to do it?

This is the structure I have:

```
> dput(head(w))
structure(list(year = c(1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004), 
    max = c(2, 48, 174, 147, 198, 573), min = c(1, 2, 14, 23, 
    44, 54), median = c(1, 26, 82, 93, 127, 140), mean = c(1.33, 
    27.28, 81.26, 93.86, 126.53, 132.39)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

The other question is how to represent this data. I started off using this code:

```
library(tidyverse)
w <- read.table("C:/Users/shall/Desktop/minmaxmeanmedian.csv", sep= ",", header=TRUE, 
                         colClasses = "numeric")
#w = read_csv("C:/Users/hhallak/Desktop/minmaxmeanmedian.csv")
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
# reshape to wide format (basically transposing the data.frame)
w <- dcast(melt(table1), variable~X)
p<-ggplot(w, aes(x=variable,ymin = `min`, 
                 ymax = `max`, lower = `min`, 
                 upper = `max`, middle = `min`)) + 
  geom_boxplot(stat = 'identity') 

p <- p + labs(y = "BAR RANGE",
              x = "VARIABLE",
              colour = "Parameter")
p <- p + theme(legend.position = c(0.8, 0.9))
p
```

This chart is probably the closest I am looking for:
[image]

Comment: Definitely read in the csv file - manual typing of data is almost always a waste of your time and a source of errors.  Check out `read.csv()` (in base R) or `read_csv()` in `readr` if you prefer tidyverse approaches.

Comment: In terms of a bar chart showing min, max, median and mean - do you want those as separate bars, stacked bars, or what?  Can you show something like what you have in mind?  `geom_bar()` is a good start.

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen I don't have anything in mind in particular, but I will edit the question and add a chart very close to what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks - from what you've shown I think the best approach to actually make a series of hovering rectangles then plot a median across them - see the approach in this answer to another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45981690/16730940

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen thank you. I was able to load the data from csv using tidyverse. The plot in the answer you provided is exactly what I am looking for. I am having difficulties making my data fit in that answer since it is organized differently. The answer uses text file that is read as a table rather than csv. I am going to see if I could use read.table instead to make it easier to use the R code.

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen I actually was able to pass that point and updated the question with the new code I am using. I am getting an error: <error/rlang_error>
Error in `geom_rect()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error:
! object 'variable' not found
---

Comment: Can you add another code block to your question with the results of `dput(head(w))` please - this will let us see the structure of your new data frame.

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen Thank you. I updated the code with the structure. I decided to change to using read.table which pretty much works the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From where you've got to (with your data frame `w` - thank you for providing the sample data) I would start with something like this:

```
p <- ggplot(w, aes(ymin = min,
                   ymax = max,
                   xmin = year - .3,
                   xmax = year + .3,
                   x = year,
                   y = median)) +
  geom_rect(fill = 'yellow', col = 'black') +
  geom_line(colour = 'blue') +
  geom_line(aes(y = mean), colour = 'red')


p
```

Which gives:
[image]

Obviously there is more to do in terms of labelling, legends etc but that is all stuff you can find in the ggplot2 documentation or many tutorials on line and tweak to your heart's content.

The important stuff from my code:

```
p <- ggplot(w, aes(ymin = min,  
                   ymax = max,
```

We are plotting the data from `w`.
The top and bottom of each bar are defined by `w$max` and `w$min` but ggplot does not require us to refer to w each time, it knows that, so we just give the column names (your `min` and `max`).

```
                   xmin = year - .3,   
                   xmax = year + .3,
```

Each column is centred around the relevant year - adding -0.3 and +0.3 just makes it wide enough to see without touching the next column.

```
                   x = year,  
                   y = median)) +
```

Speaking of years, we want the x-axis to be the years in the data set (`x = year`).
`y = median` won't be used by the rectangles, but will be used to plot our first line.

```
  geom_rect(fill = 'yellow', col = 'black') +
```

plot the rectangles, make them yellow with a black outline
(in ggplot "color" or "colour" means line colour, "fill" means fill colour).

```
  geom_line(colour = 'blue') +
```

Add our first line - the median.  I've made it blue.

```
  geom_line(aes(y = mean), colour = 'red')
```

add the second line.  since the heights for this one are the mean not median, we override the previous aesthetic with `aes(y=mean)`.  I've made this one red.

There you go - that should hopefully be enough to get your started.

Comment: Thank you for breaking down the answer. All the rest is minor and I can look it up and add it. This is perfect.